# Unit Testing and Mocking - Approach and Practice for Deeper Hierarchies - Junit and EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, easymock

I have a hierarchical list of converters like the following for example:

```
@Named
public class NameConverter {

    @Inject
    private AddressConverter addressConverter;

    public package2.Name convert(package1.Name source) {
       package2.Name target = new package2.Name();
       target.setFirstName(source.getName());
       target.setLastName(source.getName());
       target.setAddress(addressConverter.convert(source.getAddress()));
    }
}
```

and AddressConverter has ZipCodeConverter and so on ...

In the Unit Testing class,

1) I would create a mock for addressConverter - EasyMock.createNiceMock.

2) Set the expectation -

```
EasyMock.expect(addressConverter.convert(EasyMock.anyObject(package1.Address.class))).andReturn(addressList); # What this addressList should be?
```

3) Whitebox.setInternalState for private fields.

Question :

I would assert on first name and last name if they are equal which is straight forward.

But, NameConverter is also responsible for setting the converted Address.There is a possibility for NameConverter to change the values of returned converted Address and other POJOs inside.

**So how do I ensure through Asserts or something else, that NameConverter just sets the Address(and the POJOs encapsulated by it) as it is and does not tamper with the values ??**

**Possible Solution:** In the EasyMock.expect return, should I create and set values for all POJOs till the last one in the hierarchy and assert on each of the values?

But that doesn't seem like unit testing !!

Please help as how to unit test this converter.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* unit testing to set the return value of a mock object and to assert that that return value is put in the right place by your NameConverter.

However, perhaps what you're coming across is a failure of appropriate layering. If you have a set of 'converter' classes which then need to be co-ordinated in some fashion you may want to make each converter independent and to bring the co-ordination responsibility elsewhere. So, your NameConverter should be completely independent of AddressConverter and you perhaps need a third class which is responsible for calling a set of converters, which each just do their job. You could restructure each converter to be given an instance of both their input and output object and their unit tests assert that they only act on known fields within each object. Then the co-ordinator object doesn't need to know anything about what each converter does, it just needs to locate / create instances of the input and output objects and to call each converter in turn. That's very amenable to a unit-testing approach, without resulting in a lot of layering concerns.

Example code:

```
public interface Converter<S, T> {
    convert(S source, T target);
}

public class NameConverter implements Converter<p1.Name, p2.Name> {
    @Override
    public void convert(p1.Name source, p2.Name target) {
        target.setFirstName(source.getName());
        target.setLastName(source.getName());
    }
}

public class AddressConverter implements Converter<p1.Name, p2.Name> {
    @Override
    public void convert(p1.Name source, p2.Name target) {
        // more stuff.
    }
}

public class ConversionService {
    private final Set<Converter> converters;

    @Inject
    public ConversionService(Set<Converter> converters) {
        this.converters = converters;
    }

    public p2.Name convert(p1.Name source) {
        p2.Name target = new p2.Name();
        converters.forEach((converter) -> converter.convert(source, target);
        return target;
    }
}
```

Then your unit test really just need to know that all your lower-level converters were called.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest three options:

1. Return a new empty instance of address from your mock and compare that the same exact instance is set to the target. Don't test if the address value is modified. It's Ok not to test every single possibility of things going wrong.
2. Return a strict mock of address without any expectations set. It will throw if there is an attempt to modify it. And again check for instance equality.
3. Don't use mocks at all. Test the entire hierarchy as a whole. It does not look like unit testing, but it may be a good option. I think mocks are often overused and should be avoided when possible. Please see more [here](http://yefremov.net/blog/how-not-use-mocks/.).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following as a good *unit* test for `NameConverter`:

```
public final class NameConverterTest {
    @SUT
    NameConverter tested;

    @Test
    public void convertNameFromPackage1ToNameFromPackage2() {
        Address address = new Address();
        package1.Name source = new package1.Name("A Name", address);

        package2.Name converted = tested.convert(source);

        assertEquals(source.getName(), converted.getFirstName());
        assertEquals(source.getName(), converted.getLastName());
        assertNotNull(converted.getAddress());
    }
}
```

According to Martin Fowler's [definition](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html), the above *is* still a unit test for the `NameConverter` unit, even if it doesn't isolate it from its dependency on `AddressConverter` (which would have its own unit test).

(For simplicity, I used an hypothetical `@SUT` annotation which takes care of instantiating the "system under test" with injected dependencies - and actual testing libraries for this do exist.)